# Say p $> 7$ be a prime such that p $\equiv$ 1 (3). Show that the set of cubic residues (including zero) do not form an arithmetic progression.

Tags: number-theory, additive-combinatorics

I already know that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ - $\{0\}$ is partitioned into C$_{p}$, $x C_{p}$ and $ x^{2}C_{p}$ , where 'x' is a non-cubic-residue. This means that the cardinality of set of cubic residues including zero is 'k+1' where p = 3k+1.

Can anyone help me show that residues do not actually form an arithmetic progression? I am totally stumped here.

Comment: did you mean 'k' for the cardinality of the set of cubic residues?

Comment: No, I mean (k+1) because I am counting zero too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

As you indicated, there are $k+1$ cubic residues, including $0$.

$1$ and $p-1$ are cubic residues ($1^3$ and $(-1)^3$, respectively).

Comment: Yeah I still don't see it. I had made this observation earlier. Since the question says that p $>$ 7, k $ >$ 3 implying that perhaps I need to work with (k+1) $>$ 4 elements to arrive at the result